# How to copy dynamic cell contents and add to the end of a static hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am trying to write a macro which will create a hyperlink based upon the contents of the cell. For example, cell F12 contains the word "home", I would like the macro to create a hyperlink in a new cell (say, F13) which is http://www.google.com/home

The "http://www.google.com/" part of the hyperlink will always be the same, but the "home" part needs to change based upon the contents of F12.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kenny. What have you tried? Where do you get error(s), if any? Kindly refer to [MCVE] for more information how to best utilize this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/" & F12, "Go")
```